# How to set drawable with text in button android

Tags: android, android-xml, android-drawable, android-button

I am trying to set drawable in my button but its not showing properly. Here is what I want to achieve
[image]

but I am unable to get the required results.

This is what I am doing

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/btnShareStore"
                style="@style/yellowButton"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_large"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_small"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_vector_share"
                android:text="@string/lbl_share_store"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_large"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_small"/>
```

and this is how it looks like

[image]

How can I move drawable to the adjacent left side of text?

Any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try with this, keep in mind that it will need your app theme to be a descendant of `MaterialTheme`.

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        app:icon="@drawable/icon_search"
        android:text="Hello"
        app:iconGravity="textStart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```